# CSS 100% div height

Tags: css, html

I created a fiddle for my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/XJpGT/

The height of the green box should be alyways be 100% but at the same time the green and the orange box should not be bigger than the blue. I made a screen for a better understanding:

http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3736/b3oe.png

Is this possible? The content is dynamic, so all the boxes can have a different heights.

I tried to accomplish with the following code but as you can see in the fiddle it's not working like I want.

```
.right1:after {
clear: both;
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;         
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between the result you want(the picture you posted) and the result you have (the fiddle you posted)

Comment: The clear in your example clears all floats. Including the one on `div.left`. So that's the problem. Not sure about a solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/XJpGT/1/

my solution is'nt perfect, because you will have to divide the `height` between the green div, and the orange div (and the `margin` between them) manually. (in the demo, I gave 80% to the green, 10% for the orange, and 5% to the margin)
but its as close as I can get you to your goal.

**UPDATE:**
I've updated the filddle, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/XJpGT/4/

now you dont have to specify and height, the trick is caled *faux column*, and you can read about it all over the web.

in the `.right2:before, .right2:after` you specify the margin around `right2` in px.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately all of the content is generated and so the boxes must be dynamic. Not sure if this is possible with CSS.

Comment: Sure it is. Hey, the content, what kind of data is it? Is it tabular data?

Comment: Most of it is just plain text. The green box is for text, the orange for links and the blue is for text too.

Comment: Oh. Ehm, listen, can't you at least pretend it's tabular data?

Comment: @Mr Lister, post your idea.. if it fits, he will use it.

Comment: take a look at my new answer. you dont have to specify the height anymore.

Comment: Your new answer is very clever, so fortunately I don't have suggest that the OP commits a sin.